# I have to develp a model which takes series of random value and gives predicted value (in integer)

Tags: python, tensorflow, random, regression

I want to train my model on a list of number series. I don't expect it to give high accuracy but at least 25%. I have developed a small model using `Sequential()` method but at the end it is giving me output in 0.0xy.. This is really worst. I have even tried to build a model using `Neural Network` on `Azure ML workspace` but no success.

I have used the code from  [Github](https://github.com/vict0rsch/deep_learning/blob/master/keras/recurrent/recurrent_keras_power.py)! and its source from [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/using-machine-deep-learning-for-guessing-pseudo-random-generator)!

I have a file which contains 200,000 random numbers in txt format. I have converted it into csv with 150  values where 150th is the predictable value. Although initially I have taken only `2000` for easy processing with `50 size` chunks.

I have searched for this topic and found lots of questions about it but couldn't found a perfect solution.

Here is my build model code

```
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    layers = [1, 50, 100, 1]

    model.add(LSTM(
        layers[1],
        input_shape=(None, layers[0]),
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(
        layers[2],
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(
        layers[3]))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop")
    print("Compilation Time : ", time.time() - start)
    return model
```

and its running code

```
def run_network(model=None, data=None):
    global_start_time = time.time()
    epochs = 1
    ratio = 1.0
    sequence_length = 50
    path_to_dataset = open('InputNumber6_demo.txt','r+',encoding = "utf-8-sig")

    if data is None:
        print("Loading data...")
        X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = dpc.data_power_consumption(
            path_to_dataset, sequence_length, ratio)
    else:
        X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = data

    print('\nData Loaded. Compiling...\n')

    if model is None:
        model = bm.build_model()

    try:
        model.fit(
            X_train, y_train,
            batch_size=512, nb_epoch=epochs, validation_split=0.05)
        predicted = model.predict(X_test)
        predicted = np.reshape(predicted, (predicted.size,))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Training duration (s) : ', time.time() - global_start_time)
        return model, y_test, 0

    try:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(y_test[:100])
        plt.plot(predicted[:100])
        plt.show()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    print('Training duration (s) : ', time.time() - global_start_time)
    print("y_test :" ,y_test)
    print("predicted : ", predicted)
    return model, y_test, predicted
```

I am getting output in this fractions:

```
 [7.896141  7.8818192 7.8702197 7.8729057 7.887852  7.8909307 7.880986
 7.8800116 7.8971305 7.8821206 7.872368  7.8670635 7.859713  7.866045
 7.895461  7.884264  7.89429   7.891604  7.9120145 7.9183216 7.9248204
 7.9104924 7.9158993 7.897169  7.916412  7.9040785 7.920195  7.9250274
 7.933447  7.93625   7.8920164 7.9262824 7.9311395 7.936692  7.943627
 7.9117746 7.921586  7.9338064 7.9352465 7.913917  7.9132504 7.9155235
 7.892686  7.8813086 7.904029  7.902289  7.886468  7.88697   7.920277
 7.9392414 7.935853  7.9325123 7.9430776 7.9166965 7.8978596]
```

Please tell me the issue in this case or is there any algorithm to create the model

Comment: And the question arises: If you know the numbers are random and unrelated, why would you expect to achieve any success at prediction above zero? I suggest that you would built the `y` in Excel as a function of `x` and add random numbers to the `y`s.

Comment: @peter these are real random values not machine generated

Comment: @Aryerez: The asker said: "these are real random values not machine generated".  They notified me by accident.

Comment: Unless "real random values" is a phrase I am not familiar with to numbers who *are* connected to each other, and therefore can be predicted by one another, my comment remains.

Comment: Ooh I am so sorry. thanx @peter

Comment: @Aryerez but we could find a pattern among them. even 15% accuracy is acceptable